# Where is Monodevelop file templates located on windows?

Tags: monodevelop

I need to change default templates for class files to include some "using" statements. Is it possible in Monodevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to modify the built in templates, except by modifying the MonoDevelop source and recompiling it. The templates are embedded into the dlls. However, you could create an addin that adds alternative templates.